# How to dynamically call a php function in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have an index.php with the following js function:

```
function returnImageString() {
    return "<?php include 'inc/image.functions.php'; echo getRandomImages(7); ?>";        //This isn't dynamic; this will always return the same images.  How do I fix this?
}
```

However, when the page loads, the php script is called and the result is added to the source code like this:

```
function returnImageString() {
    return "images/20.11.A1B9.jpg|images/8.14.47683.jpg|images/19.10.FBB9.jpg|images/21.12.9A.jpg|images/8.11.1474937909.jpg|images/8.15.99404.jpg|images/8.10.jpg|"; //This isn't dynamic; this will always return the same images. How do I fix this?
 }
```

What I want to happen is whenever I call the js function (returnImageString), I want it to call the php function each time (since the php function returns a string of random image locations) instead of having the string hardcoded in the js function.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not possible because you're mixing client-side behavior with server-side behavior. What you need to do is create an AJAX request to the server.

If you were using a library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (which you really want to, because it makes AJAX a breeze) you would do something like this:

### PHP Code (maybe randomImages.php?)

```
// query for all images
// $_GET['limit'] will have the limit of images
// since we passed it from the Javascript
// put them all in an array like this:
$images = array('images/20.11.A1B9.jpg','images/20.11.A1B9.jpg',...);
print json_encode($images); // return them to the client in JSON format.
exit;
```

### Client Side Javascript

```
function getRandomImages(limit) {
    // make request to the server
    $.getJSON('/path/to/randomImages.php', {limit: limit}, function(data) {
        // data is now an array with all the images
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            // do something with each image
            // data[i] will have the image path
        });
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if the amount of images is finite, you can skip all this crazyness and simply have an array with all the images and generate 8 random ones from the Javascript itself. This would probably be better for smaller data sets and even some bigger ones.

Comment: unfortunately, the number of images is not finite.  I'm just grabbing x random images from the database and want to pass them to the JS to create an array.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to query the server everytime you want a new set.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to able to do this directly because PHP is interpreted on the server and you're using JavaScript on the client.  However, you if you create a page random-image.php on you server you could fetch the data using AJAX and manipulate it server side when it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Use AJAX
2. Use PHP to echo a JavaScript array (of possible image values) inside the script tags and then build a JavaScript function to randomly choose one of them when called.

The second option seems the best, in my opinion.

Comment: Hey, I actually like that second option.  Will try that out, thanks!

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  I'm not sure if that will work.  When the function is called, I want it to pull x random images from the database.  I don't think it will be feasible to build a JS array with all iamges and then randomly pick one; will be too much load on my db.

Comment: Depends how many images you store in your DB. Is better building a JS array from which to fetch elements than making an Ajax call for each JS function call. In the latter example there are more access to the DB than in the former.

Answer (score 0):

I made this a while back... maybe it can help you.
It's an example of calling a php function inside javascript with ajax. (I used gzcompress)
the php file has to be named foo.php to work with this demo.

javascript:

```
//lib
(function(a){for(var b in a)(function(c){a[b]=function(){c.apply(this,arguments);return this}})(a[b])})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.$p=function(a,b){for(b in a)this[b]=a[b];return this};

(function(a,d,i){for(i in d=document.getElementsByTagName('*'))a[d[i].id]=d[i]})(document);
//lib

function gzcompress(s,c){

    var buffer;

    (new XMLHttpRequest)

    .$p({onreadystatechange:function(){if(this.readyState>3){

        buffer = this.responseText;

    }}})

    .open("POST","foo.php",!1)
    .setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .send(
        "s="+s
        +"&"+
        "c="+c
    );
    return buffer;
}

//look! it's gzcompress inside javascript! it's magical!
document.myDiv.innerHTML = gzcompress("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",2)
```

php:

```
<?php 

echo gzcompress($_POST['s'], $_POST['c']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use my mwsX library to use your PHP functions at Javascript.

mwsX library:
https://github.com/loureirorg/mwsx

Answer (score -2):

That is commonly known as Ajax. Google for it.