# Can't call PHP function from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function

I can't call PHP-function in Javascript. My code:

```
function clearDatabase(){
$str_sql_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE categories";
if (!$result = mysql_query($str_sql_query, $link))
{
    echo "<br>Bad request<br>";
    exit();
}
echo "All deleted!";
}

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 function clickClearButton()
 {
     <?php clearDatabase(); ?> //This function don't call
 }
 </script>";
```

I already tried `"<?php clearDatabase(); ?>"`, `\"<?php clearDatabase(); ?>\"`. `clearDatabase();`.
What i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and Javascript in a client side one. You can right Javascript in PHP code, but you can't access PHP functions in Javascript.

You should really try to learn some more regarding web application development.

Comment: Take a look at [this question+answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557778/how-to-dynamically-call-a-php-function-in-javascript?rq=1) to understand more of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is run on server side and not Client side like JavaScript, you need to dynamically load the php to do this. (preferably with ajax)

A simple solution would be to put the php code into a new file called X.js
then create an empty `<script id="loadscript" src="#">` tag then change the src with javascript
`document.getElementbyId("loadscript").src="x.js";` would run the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, it won't work. Put that function in another page and then make an AJAX call to it from JavaScript.